# GSON custom object deserialisation setting all fields to null

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using GSON for the first time.  I am trying to deserialise a JSON string into a custom object, but every property of my object is set to null.  There are no parsing errors so I think the JSON properties are not mapping to the object?

Here is my code, if anyone could point out where I have gone wrong it would be much appreciated.  I have checked everything against tutorial and cannot see the problem.  The only thing is that there are more properties in the JSON string than in my object but I hope that does not matter.

JSON string:

```
{
    "_id": "D7D4A7D8219CA25848257C63000A1B50",
    "ReportingPerson": "TRAIN2 Ifap",
    "InjuredPerson": "TRAIN3 Ifap",
    "DateReported": {
        "$date": "2014-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Company": "test",
    "Division": "Learning & Development",
    "Site_id": "3CA9AD4E6066388648257B7500047D90",
    "Department_id": "724BC4B509E7B61648257363002FD645",
    "Area": "Training Room",
    "DocNo": "002223",
    "CreatedBy": "Ifap TRAIN2",
    "DateComposed": {
        "$date": "2014-01-17T01:50:23.000Z"
    },
    "OccurTime": "12:00:00",
    "Affiliation": "Employee",
    "BriefDescription": "Employee tripped over power lead in computer lab.",
    "ThirdPartyInvolvedYN": "No",
    "ThirdPartyName": "",
    "ThirdPartyAddress": [
        ""
    ],
    "ThirdPartyTel": "",
    "Classification": "Minor Injury",
    "Confidential": "",
    "ConfidentialMonitors": [
        ""
    ],
    "IncidentCategory": "2",
    "IncidentCategoryPotential": "3",
    "ReportableYN": "No",
    "ExternalBody": [
        ""
    ],
    "Authorisor": "",
    "WorkSafeConfirmedYN": "No",
    "Details": "Fell over cord in computer lab when walking through.  Held hand out to brace fall and fell on pinkie finger.",
    "Controls": [
        "Tape over cord."
    ],
    "Witnesses": [
        "No"
    ],
    "Supervisor": "TRAIN1 Ifap",
    "IntAuthorisor": "TRAIN3 Ifap",
    "IntAuthorisorNext": "",
    "AssociatedRisks": {},
    "OpenActions": {},
    "ClosedActions": {}
}
```

POJO:

```
public class Incident {

        @SerializedName("_id")
    private String _id;
    private String docNo;
    private String site_id;
    private String company;
    private String division;
    private String department_id;
    private Date dateReported;
    private String briefDescription;
    private String thirdPartyInvolvedYN;
    private String supervisor;
    private String classification;
    private String status;
    private String injuredPerson;
    private String reportingPerson;
    private Date occurDate;
    private String occurTime;

//Getters & Setters...
}
```

Main method:

```
public Incident convertJSONToBean(String json) {
        Incident i = new Incident();

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Incident>(){}.getType();

        try {
            i = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (JsonIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return i;

    }
```

Type is set correctly to Incident.class.  But any properties of the resulting Incident object are all null.

I tried commenting out all properties except _id to see if I could get just one to populate but it was still set to null.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me; there's nothing wrong with the code you have posted. I would check the actual String you're supplying to Gson.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  I tried printing out the json string within the convertJSONToBean method and it was all ok.  Properties still returning null though.  Any other ideas... I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have interesting date objects in your json string. Such as;

```
"DateReported": {
   "$date": "2014-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Which causes a `JsonParseException` because of your `Incident` class:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The date should be a string value
```

For your `Incident` class, Dates at json value should be something like;

```
"DateReported": "2014-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"
```

If you don't have an option to change dates at json value, then you should define its custom date holder class:

```
public class CustomDateHolder {
    @SerializedName("$date")
    private Date date;
    // Getters & Setters...
}
```

And change those date fields' type to `CustomDateHolder`;

```
public class Incident {
    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String _id;
    private String docNo;
    private String site_id;
    private String company;
    private String division;
    private String department_id;
    private CustomDateHolder dateReported;
    private String briefDescription;
    private String thirdPartyInvolvedYN;
    private String supervisor;
    private String classification;
    private String status;
    private String injuredPerson;
    private String reportingPerson;
    private CustomDateHolder occurDate;
    private String occurTime;
    // Getters & Setters...
}
```

Also modify your `GsonBuilder` a little bit:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

Comment: I believe the customDateHolder class is not needed.  With the @SerializedName you can traverse the tree.  I can't do a test right now but adding following annotation to the dateReported variable should work without the wrapper class: @SerializedName("DateComposed.@date")

Comment: @tom does SerializedName have an option for that?

Comment: I checked a project and if you separate names with a '.' it traverses the tree.

Comment: @tom I like to see that, can you share its link? Or try it, see if that is working or not and share it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful for helping me learn more about GSON.  I think there is an issue with my class path as even if I comment out everything except one simple property ("_id"), it is still null and I do not get any exceptions thrown.  In the end I changed to use a different JSON parsing library (JSON-simple) and it is working.  However I will use your examples next time I try GSON.

Answer (score 1):

In Json format DateComposed & DateReported properties are the Object, You need to create the 
either custom model classes for them or write CustomDeserializer class for them.

```
"DateComposed": { "$date": "2014-01-17T01:50:23.000Z" }
"DateReported": {"$date": "2014-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"}


public class Incident {

    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String _id;
    @SerializedName(value = "ReportingPerson")
    // other properties, you need to put @SerializedName on each property
             ............
   // No need to put SerializedName annotation on dateReported & dateComposed
    private Date dateReported;
    private Date dateComposed;

    @SerializedName(value = "ThirdPartyAddress")
    private List<String> thirdPartyAddress;
    @SerializedName(value = "ConfidentialMonitors")
    private List<String> confidentialMonitors;
    @SerializedName(value = "ExternalBody")
    private List<String> externalBody;
    @SerializedName(value = "Controls")
    private List<String> controls;
    @SerializedName(value = "Witnesses")
    private List<String> witnesses;
        // getter/setter
            ....
}
```

**Here is the CustomDeserializer  class for Deserializing date properties**

```
public class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Incident> {

        @Override
        public Incident deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
                JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {


            final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

            final Gson gson = new Gson();
// Parse the JsonElement tree here
            final Incident incident = gson.fromJson(json, Incident.class);
// getting date properties as string from JsonElement and parse them into date object.

            String dateReportedStr = jsonObject.get("DateReported").getAsJsonObject().get("$date").getAsString();
            String dateComposedStr = jsonObject.get("DateComposed").getAsJsonObject().get("$date").getAsString();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"); 

            try {
// setting date properties in incident object
                incident.setDateReported(df.parse(dateReportedStr));
                incident.setDateComposed(df.parse(dateComposedStr));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return incident;
        }
    }
```

**Finally Parse it**

```
final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Incident.class, new CustomDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Incident incident = gson.fromJson(Your_JSON_STR, Incident.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code examples, very useful for copying a custom deserializer.